# How to avoid repeating interface in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

It's my first app I try to build using Typescript. I want to keep styles and components in separate files to make the code more descriptive and clear. Project will consist of dozens of components and I'll use props to call the classes. Each component will look more or less like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"
import { LandingPageStyles } from "./landing-page-styles"

interface LandingPageProps {
  classes: any
}

class LandingPage extends React.Component<LandingPageProps> {

  get classes() {
    return this.props.classes;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className={this.classes.mainPage}>
        Hello Typescript
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

export default withStyles(LandingPageStyles)(LandingPage)
```

And simplified styles module :

```
import { createStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export const LandingPageStyles = () => createStyles({
  mainPage: {
    textAlign: "center",
    minHeight: "100vh",
  }
})
```

In every component I want to have the classes props with type of **any**. Is there a way to avoid declaring interface for each component? It works now but I don't like my current solution beacuse of repetition the same code in every single component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do it is as bellow. Material-ui expose `WithStyles` interface that you can inherit to include `classes` props. The main advantage is that you IDE will handle autocompletion for the defined jss class. But anyway Typescript is more verbose than Javacript. With React you often have to repeat obvious things.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {withStyles, WithStyles} from "@material-ui/core"
import { LandingPageStyles } from "./landing-page-styles"

interface LandingPageProps extends WithStyles<typeof LandingPageStyles> {
}

class LandingPage extends React.Component<LandingPageProps> {

  get classes() {
    return this.props.classes;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className={this.classes.mainPage}>
        Hello Typescript
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

export default withStyles(LandingPageStyles)(LandingPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to declare interface which extends `WithStyles` . So in component there is need to declare:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"
import { LandingPageStyles } from "./landing-page-styles"

interface LandingPageProps extends WithStyles<typeof LandingPageStyles>{

}
class LandingPage extends React.Component<LandingPageProps> {

  get classes() {
    return this.props.classes;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className={this.classes.mainPage}>
        Hello Typescript
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

export default withStyles(LandingPageStyles)(LandingPage)
```